# Selected Kendo UI grid rows to populate select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with multiple row selection enabled; I'm trying to populate an external select menu based on a few of the fields from the aforementioned row selection(s); I'm getting nowhere; can this be done? Fiddle examples?

I checked out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/UbeXn/1/), where they were populating another kendo grid based on what was selected in the first kendo grid; I figured I'd be build select options like:

```
$("#selectMenu").html("<option value=''></option>");
```

..but I can't figure out how to get the selected data OUT of the kendo grid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is not very good IMO since it only relies on jQuery instead of using the grid API. You can use the [change](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change) event to detect row changes, get the selected rows with the [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select) methd and the data items with the [`dataItem`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem) method.

So you can start with something like this:

```
$("#states").kendoGrid({
    selectable: "multiple",
    dataSource: {
        data: usStates
    },
    change: function() {
        var that = this;
        var html = "";
        this.select().each(function() {
            var dataItem = that.dataItem(this);
            html += "<option>" + dataItem.name +"</option>";
        });
        $("#select").html(html);
    }
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UbeXn/7/))

Comment: Nailed it! Agreed, I'm already using the change: event for several events, I wasn't getting how to get and loop through the selected dataItem(s).. thanks!